# Matrices and Condition Numbers

Tags: matrices

What is the realtionship between the condition number of a matrix and the condition number of the pseudoinverse of the matrix. If the original matrix is ill conditioned, is the pseudoinverse also ill conditioned ?

Answer (score 0):

Condition numbers of a matrix and its (pseudo)inverse are equal: $\kappa(A)=\|A\|\|A^{\dagger}\|$, $\kappa(A^{\dagger})=\|A^{\dagger}\|\|(A^{\dagger})^{\dagger}\|=\|A^{\dagger}\|\|A\|=\kappa(A)$.